# Significant overhead implementing Catalan numbers with histomorphism

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I'm exploring [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) recently and want to find some use cases for histomorphism - for which I think [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) could be a fun one (I'm aware there are better ways to implement Catalan numbers, which are not the focus of this question). What I come up with is the following:

```hs
import Control.Comonad.Cofree
import Control.Monad
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Function.Memoize (memoFix)
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import GHC.Natural

type Nat = Natural

-- unrelated lines omitted

catalanHisto :: Nat -> Nat
catalanHisto = histo \case
  Nothing ->
    1
  Just fs ->
    let xs = toList fs -- this is line 101 in my original code.
        ys = reverse xs
     in sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys

catalanMemo :: Integer -> Integer
catalanMemo = memoFix \q n ->
  if n == 0
    then 1
    else
      let xs = fmap q [0 .. n -1]
          ys = reverse xs
       in sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- print $ catalanMemo 1000
  print $ catalanHisto 1000
```

Performance suffers however, with `catalanHisto`:

```
real    49.36s
user    416.48s
sys     99.38s
```

which is pretty bad comparing with `catalanMemo`:

```
real    0.84s
user    5.09s
sys     2.08s
```

Given that at least it terminates, the `histo` version definitely memoized something, but there is a huge overhead that I'm not sure whether I'm misusing `histo`, or it's just the price to pay for writing programs this way. As I went ahead with some basic profiling:

```
    Sat Feb 19 22:58 2022 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       demo +RTS -N -s -p -RTS

    total time  =       20.78 secs   (52462 ticks @ 1000 us, 24 processors)
    total alloc = 122,870,767,920 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE       MODULE                 SRC                                     %time %alloc

catalanHisto.\    Catalan                src/Catalan.hs:(101,5)-(103,31)          68.0   71.5
foldMap.go        Control.Comonad.Cofree src/Control/Comonad/Cofree.hs:301:5-46   28.4   25.0
catalanHisto      Catalan                src/Catalan.hs:(97,1)-(103,31)            1.7    0.0
catalanHisto.\.ys Catalan                src/Catalan.hs:102:9-23                   1.3    3.3
```

Not an expert interpreting those results, I guess in addition to some allocations in `Control.Comonad.Cofree`, it spents a majority of time doing allocation in the non-trivial branch of `catalanHisto`, probably due to `toList` and `reverse`, which I'm not sure how much room there is for optimization.